# APIM: Retrieving policy XML from Azure Blob storage within an Azure DevOps CD pipeline fails like getting an error like The provided link ismalformed

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-api-management

APIM: I am Retrieving policy XML from Azure Blob storage within an Azure DevOps CD pipeline fails like getting an error like The provided link is mal formed.
Can any one help me on this how to resolve this

Comment: You can refer to a similar issue: [APIM: Retrieving policy XML from Azure Blob storage within an Azure DevOps CD pipeline fails](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/198c0924-7909-4c6d-8f41-340569fd67c0/apim-retrieving-policy-xml-from-azure-blob-storage-within-an-azure-devops-cd-pipeline-fails)

Comment: Do share `policy.xml` or `policy.json` and `URI` to understand the issue and help you better. Are you using the correct  extension to reference the XML file with the policy definition?

Comment: Thank you DeepDave-MT, Will inform to APIM DEV team

Comment: @DeepDave-MT  , My dev team followed your inputs but not able to resolve this, can you help me do we have any alternate option

Comment: I have to do CI-Cd for java application so using maven job completed the Build pipe Line and able to generate jar files, To do CD those artifacts need to deploy in Azure Linux VM,can you guide me how to deploy Java source in Azure Linux Vm

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned error occurs usually when wrong extension to reference the XML file with the policy definition.

Below is the sample how it looks like:

```
"properties": {  
"value": "[concat(parameters('storageAccount'), '/', 'policies.json', parameters('storageAccountSASToken'))]",  
"format": "rawxml-link"  
}
```

As DeepDave suggested check whether you are using correct extension.

Comment: Thank you SaiKarri-MT, Will inform to APIM DEV team